# Consulta javascript no controller asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta em um método da *API* (JavaScript) do **google maps**, porém pelo `controller`, é possível ?

Eu tenho uma requisição `ajax` que monta uma grid e dentro dela faço um consulta na tabela `dbo.Atlas` setando latitude e longitude para retornar o endereço, porém essa tabela não tem todos os endereço cadastros e nesse caso, precisaria executar esse procedimento para além de retornar na tela, também salvar na banco, assim da proxima vez ter esse registro na tabela.

Códigos:

```
public ActionResult ListaPosicoes(string pocsag)
        {

            dalOperador dalOper = new dalOperador();


            List<modOperadorDashLatLng> listaPosMapa = new List<modOperadorDashLatLng>();

            listaPosMapa = dalOper.pubEventosProcessadosDashMapa(pocsag);
            dalAtlasEndereco dalAtlas = new dalAtlasEndereco();

            foreach (var evento in listaPosMapa)
            {

                if (evento.latitude != 0 && evento.longitude != 0)
                {
                    evento.endereco = dalAtlas.pubTrasformaLatLongEndereco(evento.latitude.ToString(), evento.longitude.ToString());
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(evento.endereco))// caso não exista na tabela dbo.Atlas
                    {
                        evento.endereco = ""; // Endereço que deveria retornar na API do google.Maps passando como parametros a latitude e longitude

                        //Inserir na tabela dbo.Atlas passando endereço, latitude e longitude.
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    evento.endereco = "Não válido";
                }

            }
            var pontosMapa = Json(listaPosMapa, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            pontosMapa.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return pontosMapa;
        }
```

Comment: Utilize o HttpClient para fazer a requisição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Igor, se eu entendi corretamente, essa seria uma alternativa para você consumir essa api pela controller:

```
    HttpClient _servico = new HttpClient();
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
    //base da url da api
    _servico.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://url");
    //Aqui vc define se deseja o retorno em json ou xml
    _servico.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    //Se necessário autenticacao, toten...
    _servico.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("usuario", "senha");

    HttpResponseMessage resposta = _servico.GetAsync().Result;

//resposta com sucesso    
if (resposta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //Sua variavel para guardar a lista de resultados
    listaResultados = resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ResultadoAPI>>().Result;
}
```